# Function that generates a graph with specific values ​and sum in python

Tags: python, graph

I need to create a function to generate a graph with the values ​​collected at 'Uf' = MG over the years 2004 to 2021

For now i did it, function that reads data from a CSV file and returns the list of labels (column names) and data:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://app.dnpm.gov.br/DadosAbertos/ARRECADACAO/Cfem.csv'
r = requests.get(URL, allow_redirects=True)
file_name = URL.split('/')[-1]
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

    def le_df(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
        for line in file:
            df.append(line.rstrip().replace('","','";"').replace('"','').split(';'))
            df[-1][12] = df[-1][12].replace(',','.')
            df[-1][13] = df[-1][13].replace(',','.')
        
    title = df.pop(0)
    
    return title, df

title, df = le_df("Cfem.csv")

print (title, '\n')
print (df[0])
print ("Total: %d" % (len(df)))
print()

index = 0
reg = {}
for d in title:
  reg[d] = index
  index=index+1

print(reg)
```

Comment: What do you plan to graph?  There are many values for each month.  Do you want the sum?

Comment: And, by the way, since the file is almost 200MB, don't download it every time.  Download it once, and read the file.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this much harder than it needs to be.  You don't need pandas, but you can use the csv module to parse the file.  This script plots the sum of each month over the years:

```
import csv
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

yy = "Ano de Referencia"
mm = "Mes de Referencia"
dat = "Valor Recolhido (CFEM)"

data = csv.DictReader(open('x.csv', encoding='iso8859-1'))
pts = {}
for row in data:
    if row['Uf'] != "MG":
        continue
    mo = datetime.date( int(row[yy]), int(row[mm]), 1 )
    if mo not in pts:
        pts[mo] = 0
    pts[mo] += float(row[dat].replace(',','.'))

x = list(pts.keys())
y = list(pts.values())
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]